# Understand the definition of convex metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

I am trying to understand the following definition:

> We call a set $E\subset \Bbb R^k$ convex if>$$\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in E$$
>   Whenever $x\in E, y\in E$ and $0\lt \lambda \lt 1$

---

Clearly this subset of a Euclidean space must be a metric space, so we are looking at a metric space. Then we are looking at some definition which isn't an in/equality? What does this look like geometrically in a 3D case for example and why?(If this is a possible interpretation)

---

If someone can give an answer that explains the meaning, it will certainly help me in learning to 'read' the Math here. Is there a geometric interpretation?

Comment: What is your quastion?

Comment: @daw What is an easy way to understand that definition is another

Comment: @daw I like tha continued joke btw :)

Comment: Is this giving a unit ball to $E$ around all points in $E$, that makes no sense, I just don't get it

Comment: @daw Can you alert the others that the last edit made it clear and reopen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the set $\{\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\mid 0<\lambda<1\}$ is the open line segment from $x$ to $y$.

Thus your definition says that if $x,y\in E$ (convex), then the entire line segment joining $x$ to $y$ is also in $E$.

Comment: So we are filling in the area(so to speak: I mean all points) between all points?

Comment: So if we had the vertices of a cube in $\Bbb R^3$ and we were convex, we would necessarily also have the whole cube? My thoughts: we would have to have the net of the cube, but adding this we would need the whole cube(since this net fills line segments to all points in this net now)

Comment: @mehtrekspayz that is a good shout... you can draw a line between any two points in $E$ and the line will also contain $E$. Compare a circle to an 'L'-shape.

Comment: @mehtrek spayz: That's right about the cube: If you have the vertices, you get all the faces and the interior too.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! I can't believe it was that simple, you are awesome. I really have to work on being able to 'see' that from the math itself

Comment: One further question: You say 'your definition', is that intentionally implying that my definition is non-standard? Is this the same definition you know for convex?

Comment: I think the definition in your question is standard.  I wasn't implying there was anything unusual about it.  :-)

Comment: @paw Thank you once again you beautiful...!